# R package for creating multidimensional, periodic basis function?

Tags: r, statistics

I am doing some modelling work in which I am trying to parametrise an effect that varies with season and time of day. The time of day effect differs between seasons in a complex way so it seems the most general approach is to model the effect in a periodic [time of day, day of year] space.

The effect being described has a non-linear relationship to the actual predictor and predicted quantities, so I need an explicit parametrisation that I can tune using non-linear optimisation.

So, the most obvious option would be a 2D Fourier basis. Can anyone recommend an R package for generating this? I found the package fda which has the function 'create.fourier.basis' but this appears to only apply to 1D.

Beyond a Fourier approach, the sampling of the data I have is highly irregular in the [time of day, day of year] plane so ideally a more localised approach such as a periodic cubic spline in which I can place more knots in the data rich parts of the plane would be preferable. Does anyone know of an R package that creates a 2D basis for this kind of representation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **mgcv** package can create tensor product basis functions of two or more underlying basis functions. It also allows for cyclic cubic and p splines, which can be used for the variables you mention, as the underlying basis functions for the tensor product.

As **mgcv** comes with R I would start with that. Look at `?te` and `?smooth.terms` for starters.

Answer (score 0):

The fda package is suited to handle multivariate functional data. Have a look on e.g.

?fd

The help for fd states that assigning a threedimensional array to your basis function object gives you a multivariate functional data object. In their book, Ramsay, Hooker and Graves (2009) use multivariate functional data objects to capture handwriting data with a 2D definition of the pen location plus the time dimension.

Maybe I am wrong, but couldn't you just apply the same framework for your data which is defined over season, daytime, and effect?